# Unable to get access token in Angular 4 post request

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the access token via Angular 4 frontend. I have already taken the code in order to get access token. I am using OAuth v2 in LinkedIn service. 
This is the request it sent initially, 
[image]

After that angular throw, this error because of that it uses doesn't send the actual POST request. 
[image]

Is there any way to bypass this issue or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your request URL should be: `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken`. See https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 for full documentation about authentication.